# Method works in rails console, but rspec says method is undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In my rails 3 app, I have a lib folder:

```
/lib
/lib/abc/some_class.rb
/lib/abc/some_class/other.rb
```

some_class.rb:

```
module ABC
  class SomeClass
  end
end
```

other.rb

```
module ABC
  class SomeClass::Other
    def self.hello(a,b,c,)
      false
    end
  end
end
```

If I fire up rails console I can do:

```
ABC::SomeClass::Other.hello(1,2,3)
```

and it outputs false

In my rspec test, I have the same line:

```
result = ABC::SomeClass::Other.hello(1,2,3)
```

And I get:

```
undefined method 'hello' for #<Class:0x.......>
```

Is this a namespace issue? folder issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the require's in the rspec file? It needs to be including some_class.rb and some_class\other.rb (you may need to modify the load path to include both)

Comment: in my application.rb I am already autoloading all files in the /lib folder.  some_class is already working, it is  just when I added the folder some_class\other.rb that I am having this issue.

Comment: should this require be in my spec_helper or?

Comment: @Blankman please post or Gist your spec file for these tests.

Comment: require can be in either it just needs to be required. The best practice here is to require it in the file that you need it (the spec file), but if you use this class across the project, then put the require in the helper